# While exporting to XLS output is garbage even with correct headertypes

Tags: phpexcel

I have tried some solutions provided in other questions about exporting to Excel sheet using PHP,still not working.Also I referred to PHPExcel library examples still stuck.

Here's my code.

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()   ->setCreator("MeritTrac")
                                    ->setTitle("PHPExcel Test document")
                                    ->setSubject("PHPExcel Subject")
                                    ->setDescription("This is generatred by PHPExcel");

    $objPHPExcel    ->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                    ->setCellValue('A1','Hello')
                    ->setCellValue('B1','Test')
                    ->setCellValue('C1','Color')
                    ->setCellValue('D1','World');

    $objPHPExcel    ->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                    ->setCellValue('A4','Miscellaneous Glyph')
                    ->setCellValue('A5','ífá');

    $objPHPExcel    ->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


    header('Content type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    //header('Content type:application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content disposition: csv;filename="download.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
    header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header('Pragma: public');
    echo "Test print";

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
?>
<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Output: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/STmae.jpg
Please find what I am missing coz this code gives me garbage output.

Comment: Aside from `Content disposition: csv` (what is that supposed to mean) your `echo "Test print";
` is obviously wrong.... although `?>
<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>` is pretty meaningless

Comment: You ___cannot___ send any other output to `php://output` (e.g. echo anything) when you're sending a file, otherwise that echoed output will corrupt your file

Comment: Thank you for pointing out.